# Search in a file with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I need to search in a file like a hash. Wondering if awk is right solution

Input example:

```
bla   123.123.123.0
# This line should be a comment
ble      www.ble.com
bli  <random whitespace> ::1
blo   anything
```

I need two different outputs depending on the context:

Get keys:

```
bla ble bli blo
```

And search(ble)

```
www.ble.com
```

I was hoping that this is trivial with `awk`

**Edit:** Improved description for input format

Comment: What exact output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way like this(not very clear with requirement):

```
$ awk '!/^#/{a[$1]=$2}END{print a[x];}' x='ble' file
www.ble.com
```

Answer (score 1):

get keys:

```
kent$  grep -oP "^\w+(?= )" file
bla
ble
bli
blo
```

if you want them in one line with awk

```
kent$  awk 'NR!=2{printf $1" "}' test
bla ble bli blo
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear about the format... How about this for a start?

```
$ awk '/^[^#]/{print $1}/www/{print $2}' input.txt
bla
ble
www.ble.com
bli
blo
```

or "two different outputs:

```
/^[^#]/ {
    k[$1]++
}
/www/ {
    w[$2]++
}

END {
    print "keys:"
    for (x in k)
        print "\t"x
    print "urls:"
    for (x in w)
        print "\t"x
```

}

output:

```
$ awk -f keys.awk input.txt
keys:
    bla
    ble
    bli
    blo
urls:
    www.ble.com
```